# What is wrong with a program?

Tags: c, file

Programm crushes, help me please, thanks in advance. The file can be downloaded below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int deed_id;
    char deed_name[55];
    int points_for_deed;
    int total_times_done;
    int total_points_earned;
} deed;

int main(){
    FILE *file1;
    file1=fopen("deed_list.txt", "r");
    if(file1==NULL){
        printf("Can not open the file");
        return 1;
    }
    int j;
    fscanf(file1, "%i", &j);
    deed  **deed_list = (deed**)malloc(sizeof(deed)*j);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<j; i++){
        fscanf(file1, "%i %s %i", &deed_list[i]->deed_id, deed_list[i]->deed_name, &deed_list[i]->points_for_deed);
    }
    printf("%i",j);
    fclose(file1);
    return 0;
}
```

https://sst-csci.com/csci151/wp-content/uploads/deed_list.txt

Comment: `deed  **deed_list = (deed**)malloc(sizeof(deed)*j);` --> `deed  *deed_list = malloc(sizeof(deed)*j);`, `&deed_list[i]->deed_id` --> `&deed_list[i].deed_id` and so on.

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Also in C casting malloc & friends is useless.

Answer (score 1):

```
deed  **deed_list = (deed**)malloc(sizeof(deed)*j);
```

You don't want a pointer to pointer to store an array of `deed`, change to a single pointer (and don't cast `malloc`):

```
deed  *deed_list = malloc(sizeof(deed)*j);
```

Don't forget to call `free(deed_list);` at the end.